# Some Kind Of PHP Replace

Tags: php, html

I have this html tag

```
<a href="<navigation>3</navigation>">Go Here</a>
```

I want to find any and all references to `<navigation></navigation>`, retrieve the int value thats between the `<navigation>3</navigation>` (in this case the number 3), run an sql query and return a record where the id is the value between `<navigation>3</navigation>` (again in this case 3) and replace the entire tag  with whatever was returned from the sql query.

note: there could be more than one navigation tag within my string. plus a bunch of other html. i want to keep all the other and find, build, and replace new text where the navigation tag is.

Comment: How is that even correct HTML?

Comment: @BoltClock I don't think it's supposed to be. Finally, a HTML question that can't be solved with a DOM parser! :)

Comment: will the `navigation` tags always contain only numbers?

Comment: `retrieve the int value, run an sql query and replace ` is the most complicated and messy design I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). You can search for `<navigation>\d+</navigation>` and change it in the callback function.

Comment: @Pekka -> The navigation tag will always contain only numbers yes